# Javascript - sorting arrays containing positive and negative "decimal" numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I originally had the following callback passed as a parameter to the javascript array `sort()` function:

```
function sortNumber(a,b) {
return a-b;
}
```

However this doesn't work when my array contains positive and negative decimal numbers (i.e. -107.578, 97.453 etc.)  How would I modify this to sort properly?

Comment: This callback function will sort an array of decimal numbers in ascending numerical order. Did you want it to do something different?

Comment: Uh... this should work regardless.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't see any problems with that function. Here's my test code:

```
var nums = [10, 5, 40, 25, -3412,4212, -107.578, 97.453];

function sortNumber(a,b){
   return a - b;
}

alert( nums.sort(sortNumber) );
```

Can you show some more of your code? It might be a problem with the array.

Comment: sorry my fault, careless error in my code.  this does work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
nums.sort(function(a, b) {
           if (a < 0 && b < 0  || a > 0 && b > 0) {
              return a-b; 
            } else if (a < 0) {
              return -1; 
            } else if (b < 0) {
             return 1; 
            } 
           });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).